# Can't add a choice form field on custom usercreateform

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been trying to create a custom signup form using an extended user model in django. One of the custom fields I've been trying to add is a user type which can only be either "Employee" or "Admin".

My signUpForm class looks like this

```
from .models import EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES 

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
usertype = forms.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    choices=EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES,
)
userID = forms.CharField(label="User ID")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'userID', 'usertype')
```

EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES comes from my models.py which look like this

```
EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('admin', 'Admin'),
    ('employee', 'Employee'),
)
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ADMIN = 'Admin'
EMPLOYEE = 'Employee'
EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
    (EMPLOYEE, 'Employee'),
)
usertype = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    choices=EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CHOICES,
)
userID = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
)
```

When running the server, I receive the error
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

Is there a different method for adding the choices to my form field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your error is due to using CharField instead of using ChoiceField. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Even though what are you trying to accomplish wont work with the form created. You have to create a ModelForm for your Profile model. Then you can render the field simply on a template.